# Trailer tire gone -- use spare or replace pair?

Tags: tires, trailer, spare-tire

Some rebar popped a tire (ST205/75R14) on my dual axle 3500lb 26ft camping trailer.

I'm not sure the year or mileage (bought the trailer used last year), but wear suggests the 4 tires have 60% of their life left.

I also have a unused full spare.

Options, in order of decreasing price:

1. Replace 4 tires. Seems unnecessarily expensive as (a) it's "only" a trailer and (b) I'm not even halfway through their lifetime. (And heck, what if I kill another tire?)
2. Replace 2 tires on one axle, and have two different pairs.
3. Use the spare tire, and replace it. The spare's wear doesn't match the other 3 wheels.

What's the recommended approach to take?

Answer (score 1):

If the axles are not driven then there is no real issue of having a part-worn in front or behind a full one.

The problem comes when the axle is driven - specially with some 4wd - as the differentials need to allow for different rolling differences due to corners.